# Firefox 79 - cannot reenable tracking protection (button missing)?

Tags: firefox

So, I use Firefox 79 on Ubuntu; I tried to look on a ebay page in Private mode, there were no images because of tracking protection ( see: [There are no pictures showing on ebay using firefo... - The eBay Community](https://community.ebay.co.uk/t5/Technical-Difficulties/There-are-no-pictures-showing-on-ebay-using-firefox/td-p/6710633) ). So I turned off tracking protection, images showed up and I looked at them, then I wanted to re-enable tracking protection again - unfortunately, there is no such button:

[image]

How do I re-enable tracking protection for a page, once I had turned it off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the image you provided, there is a toggle switch just to the right of the text saying "Enhanced Tracking Protection is turned OFF for this site". Use it to reenable Enhanced Tracking Protection.[image: An image detailing where the said button is]

Comment: Oh wow, there was a button there? Could not see it with the contrast on my monitor - not even in the screenshot I myself took! `:)` Thanks - that red outline was all I needed `:)`

Comment: You're welcome. If you think this is a problem with firefox you can file a bug report [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/home)

Comment: In Preferences --> Privacy & Security --> Enhanced Tracking Protection --> Manage Exceptions, you can also remove the site from the list.